# Can you submit a Post request over https to an iframe, from a form that is in http?

Tags: forms, iframe, https

I've got a pretty form that loads on any page on the site to prompt a user to login. However this can be from any http page.

The login form processing script however is in https, or at least it should be so that the information is secure.

Can I submit the login request via POST if i specify in the action that it should be sent over https?

Comment: Does your https-form has the iframe as target? If it does, does it work on firefox or you get your POST request aborted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. you just set the (login form ) action to https URL with method POST.

Comment: does it submit the info over https though or http?